# GAMS Definition of a Subset with k and k+1

Tags: set, subset, linear-programming, indices, gams-math

So I have the following set:

```
i 1,2,3,...,I
j 1,2,3,...,J
k 1,2,3,...,K with k´2,3,4,...,K
```

I am defining my set and my parameters via GDX-import through a Excel Sheet so I can change the Set and the parameters dynamically in order to do a calculation study with a linear-programming model.

How do I define this kind of set with k´ so it works with parameters like d_kk´(Distance from k to k´) and t_jkk´?

Keep in mind that the solution has to work on a large scale at least 1,...,100 for every indice.

Thanks a lot.
Cheers,
SAM

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: The question is a bit hard to read. I think what you have from Excel is a set `k`, and now you want a set `k1` that has one less element (first element dropped). This can be done with `set k1(k); k1(k)$(ord(k)>1) = yes`; Always check with `display k1;`. As `k1` is a dynamic set, remember to declare `parameter d(k,k)` instead of `parameter d(k,k1)`. (you can use `d(k,k1)` when referencing `d`).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you whant to calculate the distance between different points in set k. Use a alias set and a multidimentional set:

```
Set i /1*I/
    j /1*J/
    k /1*K/
    kk(k,k);
alias(ka,k);

kk(k,ka)$(ord(k)<ord(ka))=yes;

parameter 
    x(k) 'x-koordinate'
    y(k) 'y-koordinate'
    d(k,k) 'Distance from k to ka';

x(k)=uniform(0,1);
y(k)=uniform(0,1);

d(k,ka)$kk(k,ka)=sqrt((x(k)-x(ka))^2+(y(k)-y(ka))^2);
```